# Формат координат геолокации в Android

Tags: java, android, геолокация

```
private String formatLocation(Location location) {
    if (location == null)
        return "";
    return String.format(
            "Coordinates: lat = \n%1$.6f\n, lon = \n%2$.6f\n, time = \n%3$tF %3$tT",
            location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), new Date(
                    location.getTime()));
}
```

НО:

Если язык телефона стоит русский - приходят координаты в стиле "53,66678" (запятая)

А на англ.языке телефона "53.66678" (точка)

В приложении еще происходит работа с координатами и этот элемент (точка/запятая) один из ключевых.

Как привести данные геолокации к одному виду независимо от языка устройства?

Comment: Еще примечание: у вас координаты float если не ошибаюсь - вот с ними и работайте. Float -> String -> Float это плохая идея.

Comment: @virex-84 я работаю со всей строкой "Coordinates: lat = \n%1$.6f\n, lon = \n%2$.6f\n, time = \n%3$tF %3$tT". ваш вариант с "Locale.US" отлично вписался! спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Я про другое: все операции связанные с координатами (+, -, *, /, и т.д.) нужно делать в float, а вывод в виде текста который зависит от текущей локали пользователя - вот тут установка локали в единый вид и пригодится.

Comment: @virex-84 да, для этого и надо) а то я просто через split заменял запятую на точку. можно было бы пофиксить просто через replace (тогда бы не падало). но стало интересно как сделать один общий вид для всех языков. да и странно вообще, что есть разница в формате из-за языка.

Comment: Ничего странного нет. Если у вас есть windows - там точно также точка либо запятая в зависимости от региональных настроек. И формат даты так же другой для США.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
return String.format(
            Locale.US,
            "Coordinates: lat = \n%1$.6f\n, lon = \n%2$.6f\n, time = \n%3$tF %3$tT",
            location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), new Date(
                    location.getTime()));
```

либо так:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en_US");
return String.format(
            locale,
            "Coordinates: lat = \n%1$.6f\n, lon = \n%2$.6f\n, time = \n%3$tF %3$tT",
            location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), new Date(
                    location.getTime()));
```